# Should I really use REGEX or stay with dirty Java IF statements ? (For performance)

Tags: java, regex, optimization

Here is the code !

```
private boolean isIdCorrect(String userIdToAdd) {
    boolean checkValues = true;
    if(userIdToAdd.length() == 18) {
        if(userIdToAdd.charAt(0) == '#'
                && userIdToAdd.charAt(7) == '@') {
            for(int i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
                if(!((userIdToAdd.charAt(i) >= 'a'
                        && userIdToAdd.charAt(i) <= 'f')
                        || (userIdToAdd.charAt(i) >= '0'
                                && userIdToAdd.charAt(i) <= '9'))) {
                    checkValues = false;
                }
                if(!checkValues) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 8 ; i < 18 ; i++) {
                if(!((userIdToAdd.charAt(i) >= 'a'
                        && userIdToAdd.charAt(i) <= 'f')
                        || (userIdToAdd.charAt(i) >= '0'
                        && userIdToAdd.charAt(i) <= '9'))) {
                    checkValues = false;
                }
                if(!checkValues) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The goal is to return true if the String looks like #[6 char long hex string]@[8 char long hex string], else we return false.

Here is the regex : /#[0-9a-f]{6}@[0-9a-f]{8}/

As you can see it looks like dirty, but, it is really bad besides REGEX, in terms of performance ?

Thank you in (GameBoy) advance (SP) !

Comment: It is true that regex evaluation is costly compared to other operations. The question is rather: Do you care? Do you have to do the check hundreds of times per second? Does the user experience degrade?

Comment: You'd have to benchmark the difference for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few reasons why you should probably use a regex.

- **Readability**. The Regex matching will be much easier to read (3 lines vs. ~30) than the if's and for-loops used here.
- **It's the tool for the job**. This is exactly what Regex's are for. Why re-invent the wheel (in a non-reusable way)?
- **Performance**. Despite what you may think, the Regex performance is not really bad enough to be considered here. In fact, it's probably better than the code you have written as a replacement. Only benchmarks will be able to tell.

Comment: Readability is what matters. This is a nano-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you have a code with a lot of nested loops and conditionals, the first reflex is to try to design it better, example:

```
private boolean isHexChar(char c) {
    return (c > '/' && (c < ':' || c > '`' && c < 'g')); 
}

private boolean isIdCorrect(String userIdToAdd) {
    if( userIdToAdd.length() != 18 || userIdToAdd.charAt(0) != '#' || userIdToAdd.charAt(7) != '@') {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<7; i++) {
        if (!isHexChar(userIdToAdd.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(int i=8; i<18; i++) {
        if (!isHexChar(userIdToAdd.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Once done you can try to compare the speed with a regex (if you think it's important), but note that now the situation is different since you have a more readable (and probably faster) code.

Comment: @PierreBlandet: yes because the idea is to return `false` as soon as possible and to avoid the most possible tests. It will be interesting too if you benchmark it vs a regex way, because the result isn't obvious in particular with compiled languages (or pseudo-compiled languages). Take care if you do that to use the good method (i.e. the `matches` method).